# Issue with Polyline tools in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, polyline

I used the following code ->

```
const double CAMERA_ZOOM = 16;
const double CAMERA_TILT = 80;
const double CAMERA_BEARING = 30;
const LatLng SOURCE_LOCATION = LatLng(42.747932, -71.167889);
const LatLng DEST_LOCATION = LatLng(37.335685, -122.0605916);


class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapPageState();
  }

 class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();

Set<Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();
List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
PolylinePoints polylinePoints;
String googleAPIKey = 'API_KEY';

BitmapDescriptor sourceIcon;
BitmapDescriptor destinationIcon;

 LocationData currentLocation;
```

// a reference to the destination location

```
 LocationData destinationLocation;
  Location location;
  double pinPillPosition = -100;
   PinInformation currentlySelectedPin = PinInformation(
  pinPath: '',
  avatarPath: '',
  location: LatLng(0, 0),
  locationName: '',
  labelColor: Colors.grey);
   PinInformation sourcePinInfo;
     PinInformation destinationPinInfo;

    @override
       void initState() {
         super.initState();
```

// creating an instance of Location

```
location = new Location();
polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData cLoc) {
 
  currentLocation = cLoc;
  updatePinOnMap();
  });
   setSourceAndDestinationIcons();
```

// setting the initial location

```
  setInitialLocation();
 }

  void setSourceAndDestinationIcons() async {
    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0), 'assets/driving_pin.png')
        .then((onValue) {
     sourceIcon = onValue;
    });

     BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.0),
            'assets/destination_map_marker.png')
        .then((onValue) {
      destinationIcon = onValue;
       });
      }

    void setInitialLocation() async {

        currentLocation = await location.getLocation();
           destinationLocation = LocationData.fromMap({
              "latitude": DEST_LOCATION.latitude,
             "longitude": DEST_LOCATION.longitude
         });
       }

          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
             zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
         tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
     bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
    target: SOURCE_LOCATION);
   if (currentLocation != null) {
    initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
      zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
      tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
      bearing: CAMERA_BEARING);
     }
      return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
          markers: _markers,
          polylines: _polylines,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
          onTap: (LatLng loc) {
            pinPillPosition = -100;
          },
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            controller.setMapStyle(Utils.mapStyles);
            _controller.complete(controller);
            // my map has completed being created;
            // i'm ready to show the pins on the map
            showPinsOnMap();
          }),
      MapPinPillComponent(
          pinPillPosition: pinPillPosition,
          currentlySelectedPin: currentlySelectedPin)
            ],
         ),
       );
   }

  void showPinsOnMap() {
 // get a LatLng for the source location
// from the LocationData currentLocation object
var pinPosition =
    LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
// get a LatLng out of the LocationData object
var destPosition =
    LatLng(destinationLocation.latitude, destinationLocation.longitude);

sourcePinInfo = PinInformation(
    locationName: "Start Location",
    location: SOURCE_LOCATION,
    pinPath: "assets/driving_pin.png",
    avatarPath: "assets/friend1.jpg",
    labelColor: Colors.blueAccent);

destinationPinInfo = PinInformation(
    locationName: "End Location",
    location: DEST_LOCATION,
    pinPath: "assets/destination_map_marker.png",
    avatarPath: "assets/friend2.jpg",
    labelColor: Colors.purple);


  _markers.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('sourcePin'),
    position: pinPosition,
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        currentlySelectedPin = sourcePinInfo;
        pinPillPosition = 0;
      });
    },
    icon: sourceIcon));
// destination pin
_markers.add(Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('destPin'),
    position: destPosition,
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        currentlySelectedPin = destinationPinInfo;
        pinPillPosition = 0;
        });
      },
      icon: destinationIcon));

      setPolylines();
    }

        void setPolylines() async {
          List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
             googleAPIKey,
            currentLocation.latitude,
            currentLocation.longitude,
            destinationLocation.latitude,
            destinationLocation.longitude);

         if (result.isNotEmpty) {
         result.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
          polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
        });

       setState(() {
           _polylines.add(Polyline(
           width: 2, // set the width of the polylines
            polylineId: PolylineId("poly"),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 122, 198),
            points: polylineCoordinates));
              });
          }
        }

   void updatePinOnMap() async {

    CameraPosition cPosition = CameraPosition(
    zoom: CAMERA_ZOOM,
    tilt: CAMERA_TILT,
    bearing: CAMERA_BEARING,
    target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
   );
   final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;

    setState(() {
        
    var pinPosition =
      LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);

       sourcePinInfo.location = pinPosition;


       _markers.removeWhere((m) => m.markerId.value == 'sourcePin');
         _markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('sourcePin'),
       onTap: () {
         setState(() {
           currentlySelectedPin = sourcePinInfo;
          pinPillPosition = 0;
              });
               },
             position: pinPosition, // updated position
            icon: sourceIcon));
       });
      }
          }
```

I only see the pin that moves if the position changes but no path, only the animation of the pin that moves on the map . Could you please tell me what could be the important part to monitor in order to draw the path traced on the screen while the pins move on the screen?

Comment: I removed the API key from your code, please dont share API keys on public websites